Assignment to global variable attribute in for loop is not available outside the scope of the loop
This is a simplified version of this SO question (link) with some program output.
Using Python and networkX under macOS, I am not able to assign a value to an edge attribute as follows:
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pyvis.network import Network
from io import StringIO

csv_cities= """City,Location,Lon,Lat,x,y,,LonDat,LatDat
Los Angeles,"Los Angeles, California, United States",-118.254190,34.048050,140,328,q,-123.114980,25.761681
New York,"New York, New York, United States",-74.005994,40.712749,1415,591,q,-71.056800,51.045700
Atlanta,"Atlanta, Georgia, United States",-84.389854,33.750800,1116,316,q,-94.971032,39.002842
Chicago,"Chicago, Illinois, United States",-87.632360,41.881954,1022,638,q,52.05818,25.284019 """

csv_connections= """City1,City2,numTracks,NumCarSpots,Colors,SegmentTotalCarSpots
Chicago,Los Angeles,1,4,Blue,4
New York,Chicago,2,2,"Orange, Black",4
Atlanta,Chicago,1,3,Blue,3"""

cities = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_cities))
interCityConnections = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_connections))

G = nx.Graph()          

#Add cities to graph
coords={}
for index, row in cities.iterrows():
    print(f"{row['City']:<17} {int(row['x']):<6} {int(row['y']):<6}")
    G.add_node(row['City'],city=True, x=row['x'], y=row['y'], physics=False, 
    label=row['City'], title=f'{row['x']},{row['y']}')
    coords[row['City']]=int(row['x']),int(row['y']) 
    
print("- 1 - ")

#Add intercity connections
for index, row in interCityConnections.iterrows():    
    print(f"{row['City1']:>17} <-{row['NumCarSpots']} {row['Colors']}-> {row['City2']:<17} ")
    G.add_edge(row['City1'],row['City2'],interCity=True,numTracks=row['numTracks'])
    G[row['City1']][row['City2']]['taxes']="Major"  # This works
    shortPaths=nx.all_shortest_paths(G,row['City1'], row['City2'])
    G[row['City1']][row['City2']]['shortPaths']=shortPaths  #some assignment happens here
                                                            # but value not usable outside loop?
    for p in shortPaths:    #This works
        print(f"Path:{p}")  #This works

print("- 2 - ")
    
print(G['Atlanta']['Chicago'])
print(f"type:{type(G['Atlanta']['Chicago']['shortPaths'])}")
for p in G['Atlanta']['Chicago']['shortPaths']: 
    print("For looping...") # This never executes
    print(f"Path:{p}")      # This never executes
print("Done. There should be a path displayed above this line.")

This is the output:
q@q-mbp ttr % py simplebug.py
Los Angeles       140    328   
New York          1415   591   
Atlanta           1116   316   
Chicago           1022   638   
- 1 - 
          Chicago <-4 Blue-> Los Angeles       
Path:['Chicago', 'Los Angeles']
         New York <-2 Orange, Black-> Chicago           
Path:['New York', 'Chicago']
          Atlanta <-3 Blue-> Chicago           
Path:['Atlanta', 'Chicago']
- 2 - 
{'interCity': True, 'numTracks': 1, 'taxes': 'Major', 'shortPaths': <generator object _build_paths_from_predecessors at 0x10d107480>}
type:<class 'generator'>
Done. There should be a path displayed above this line.

So, how can I modify an edge attribute from inside that for loop and have the change persist outside the scope of the loop?
How can I access the result of this assignment:
G[row['City1']][row['City2']]['shortPaths']=shortPaths 

outside the for loop?
This feels like some kind of scope bug, but I admittedly am quite new to both Python and networkX. I wonder if I should be passing G into the for loop somehow, but I am at a loss.

It seems like you are printing out the values from the generator in two different places. Generators are read once and done, so the second for loop will not yield any results. It works for me if I comment out either print, so the other is the only one evaluating the generator. If you intend to reuse the output, consider list(nx.all_shorted_paths(...)) so it reads the generator once only.

Use G[row['City1']][row['City2']]['shortPaths'] = list(shortPaths) as shortest path is a generator and you exhaust it with for p in shortPaths

DOh! Yes.  That worked.  Thank you. If you post this as an answer I will accept.

And uhh... thanks for tipping me off that generators get exhausted.  Did not realize they were a one time thing.

Answer is in the comments as well.  Thanks to:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766544/kenny-ostrom
https://stackoverflow.com/users/218663/jonsg
... for the help.
This was an instance of my misunderstanding how Python generators work. Switching to:
 G[row['City1']][row['City2']]['shortPaths'] = list(shortPaths)

Works just fine.
I thought it was interesting how this example of my misunderstanding and learning about generators seemed to mimic a scope violation.  Maybe a tip-off for others who find themselves struggling in a similar manner.

As an aside, keep in mind that Python does not have block-defined scopes. There is the built-in scope, one global scope per module, and one local scope per function. (There is also a notion of "non-local scope", wherein free variables in a nested function can refer to a variable in an enclosing function's local scope.)
